# On CircleCI, how can I trigger one build after another, but only if the first is green

Tags: circleci

I've managed to create a CircleCI build that triggers a subsequent build using their API using `curl`. I've added this to my `circle.yml`:

```
test:
 override:
  - mvn test -s settings.xml
  - mvn deploy -Prun-its -s settings.xml
  - curl -v -X POST https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/alexec/docker-maven-plugin/tree/master?circle-token=$CIRCLE_TOKEN
```

How do I trigger only if all of the previous steps are green?

Comment: It would seem `$CIRCLE_TOKEN` only auths the current repo (or something), to trigger a second private repo you need to generate an API key and save it in an env var.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should do this in the `deployment` section: Since this is - by definition - only run if everything is fine, this should do the trick.

See [their documentation on deployment](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#deployment) for details. There it says:

> These commands are triggered only after a successful (green) build.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `requires` variable in your job that you want to run only if the previous job has run. So you give the `requires` variable a value of the job name that you want to succeed first before the jobs resume running.

See this example: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/